# Created a code to greet the user and made an embed, no errors except one

Tags: discord, discord.py

Created a code to greet the user and made an embed, no errors except one:

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def on_member_join(ctx):
    await client.fetch_channel(id)(869212882968145992)

    embed=discord.Embed(title="new  member", description="oook", color=0xFFFF00)
    
    embed.add_field(name="Command1", value="What it does", inline= True)
    embed.add_field(name="Command2", value="What it does", inline= True)

    await ctx.send( embed = embed)
```

Error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1):

You already specified the id parameter, put this:

```py
await client.fetch_channel(869212882968145992)
```

Instead of:

```py
await client.fetch_channel(id)(869212882968145992)
```

Comment: Same mistake : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Which line on your code?

Comment: I don't know, maybe I should rewrite all the code again?